# how to display Image in Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

im trying to display an image in vue component

```
<img :src="profile.photoes[0].picture"/>
```

(like this), but i m not getting it.

However, if i do

```
<img :src="'../../'+profile.photoes[0].picture"/> ( I m able to get the image.
```

why there are two behaviour of the same line of code. Does the folders in Laravel view, makes any difference ??

Comment: <img :src="'../../'+profile.photoes[0].picture" >

Comment: <img :src="profile.photoes[0].picture">

Comment: both are pointing to different location. second one is pointing to 2 level up while first one is pointing to the same folder where file exist.

Comment: both are showing image, in two different component. why so..

Comment: use root path instead which will give you uniform path like `/app/images/abc.png` or `/images/abc.png`

Comment: I guess both component are in different location right ?

Comment: i m using it in vue components.  (for both of the component, the images folder is same in public folder of laravel)

Comment: @c2486 both components are in same folder

Comment: Then you are using different `level` of route for both ? for first `xxxx` and for second `xxxx/xxxx/xxxx`

Comment: u r right, c2486. Routes are /xxx and /xxx/xxx/xxx. Thanks